# Using old style function definition in C giving error in MinGW compiler

Tags: c, function, dev-c++

I am working on C image processing by dwayne phillips and using its source code to understand the basics of image processing. All the functions in the source code are given in different style that i normally use

Here i give a normal function that is given in the source code.i  used dev c++ with `minGW` compiler to compile the code having the function

```
edm8(in_name, out_name, the_image, out_image,
                  il, ie, ll, le, value)
           char   in_name[], out_name[];
           int    il, ie, ll, le;
           short  the_image[ROWS][COLS],
                  out_image[ROWS][COLS],
                  value;
        {
       int    a, b, count, i, j, k;

       create_file_if_needed(in_name, out_name, out_image);

       read_tiff_image(in_name, the_image, il, ie, ll, le);

       for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
          for(j=0; j<COLS; j++)
             out_image[i][j] = 0;

          /***************************
          *
          *   Loop over image array
          *
          ****************************/

       printf("\n");

       for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++){
          if( (i%10) == 0) printf("%3d", i);
          for(j=0; j<COLS; j++){
             if(the_image[i][j] == value)
                out_image[i][j] = distance_8(the_image, i, j, value);
          }  /* ends loop over j */
       }  /* ends loop over i */

       write_array_into_tiff_image(out_name, out_image,
                                   il, ie, ll, le);

    }  /* ends edm8 */
```

now when i compile any function like above i am getting these 2 errors

```
 [Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token  
 [Error] expected unqualified-id before '{' token in
```

I am not able to track down ,debug and understand the cause of their generation??

Comment: Talking about constructors and destructors means you're definitely not compiling it as a C file. You can't always get away with compiling C code as C++. They're two separate languages.

Comment: @chris sir i am compiling it as file with .c extension.

Comment: File extensions are irrelevant, you still have to use the correct compiler. I think MingW is GCC, so you should use `gcc` instead of `g++`.

Answer (score 2):

The following message :
[Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

Let me think that you are in fact compiling in C++, and not in C.

Double check that you are really compiling in C and not C++ by setting the correct build options in your environment. Many IDE compile by default and C++ even if the files have .c extension.

Comment: when i compiled the same code by copy pasting it to a blank file without changing anything then its compiling without any errors!!i am not able to understand the reason for this??